# Firestore queried Document output 'undefined' and after few moments shows the correct data that is stored in Firestore in Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple query function which has the Firestore query inside a for loop to query all the documents inside my js file and whenever I run it on the terminal the first line of the output is undefined and then the actual expected output gets displayed.

*sidenote: I have only three documents in firestore and each with a unique id as id_1, id_2 and id_3*

here's the code:

```
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); //firebaseConfig is a variable that hold the configuration details

        //Query Funtion
        function queryFirestore() {

            var database = firebase.firestore();

            for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                let id = database.collection("sampleCollection").doc(`id_${i}`);

                let getData = id.get().then(doc => {
                    if (!doc.exists) {
                        console.log("[!] Doc does not exists");
                    }
                    else {
                        var data = doc.data();
                        console.log(data['delayed']); //delayed is a boolean field in the Firestore Document
                    }

                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log("[:(] Error: ", err);
                })
            }

        }

queryFirestore();
```

Output:

```
undefined
false
false
true
```

Comment: count the number of `console.log` in your code. there might be place where you might be logging something undefined but is not in the code. for surity change the line `console.log(data['delayed']);` to `console.log("delayed : " + data['delayed']);`. if you get a log `delayed : undefined` then comment ;)

Comment: yeah, I found the error I was calling the function inside a `console.log` which was causing the undefined to come as the output. Thanks for the help.

Comment: now it seems that i have almost done all sorts of errors while coding  this was one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to I was calling the function inside a console.log which was causing the undefined to come as the output.